# Script to insert line into files in sub-dirs

Tags: linux, scripting

I have a sub-dir tree with varying number of branches and most of
the branches contain .cpp files (many of them). I have a header-file
at the root of the tree that I want to have as a

```
#include "<constructed-relative-path-to-root>/headerfile.h"
```

as the first line of each .cpp.
an alternative to `constructed-relative-path-to-root` would be the
hard-coded path, which would have to be adjusted whenever the project is relocated)
a second alternative would be to copy the content of the header-file in at the top of each .cpp file

I have no idea how to write such a script. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can't you just add the root to your compiler's include path and use `#include <headerfile.h>` everywhere?

Comment: @JimParis: Yes, that will also work; the problem remains to add the line `#include <headerfile.h>` in each .cpp in all the sub-dirs - there are hundreds - This would be solved by Doug O'Neal's answer :)

Comment: If you're using GCC, you could go one step further and use `-include headerfile.h` on the command line.  No source code changes at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the root of your tree run

```
find . -name \*cpp | while read FILE
do
    sed -i '1i #include "rootpath/headerfile.h"' "$FILE"
done
```

Comment: That will work for the first alternative, and can be expanded to pick up the `pwd` automatically. thx

Comment: Adjusting your answer to Jim Paris' comment would give the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

I got hold of this on [CLUG](http://wiki.clug.org.za/wiki/Main_Page)-mailing list:

```
base=$(pwd)
find . -type f -iname '*.cpp' | while read f ; do
   curr=$(dirname $f)
   relpath=$(python -c "import os.path; print os.path.relpath('$base',
'$curr')")
   sed -i -e '1i#include "'$relpath/headerfile.h'"' "$f"
done
```

Copy the above code into a file, make it executable and run from commandline.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to include a header file at the start of every source file you build, and you're using gcc, you don't need to change your files at all; you can simply add:

```
-include headerfile.h
```

to the gcc command line.  From the man page:

```
   -include file
       Process file as if "#include "file"" appeared as the first line of
       the primary source file.  However, the first directory searched for
       file is the preprocessor's working directory instead of the
       directory containing the main source file.  If not found there, it
       is searched for in the remainder of the "#include "..."" search
       chain as normal.
```

Comment: I was not aware of this - very handy to test stuff before making changes fixed for porting to other platforms.